# Валидаций двух и более обьектов в WPF (Validation WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, валидация

У меня в диалогом окне есть 5 элементов xaml  texbox у каждый элемент имеет свою валидацию

```
            <xctk:WatermarkTextBox Watermark="{Binding FirstNameBtnText}"
                               x:Name="FirstNameTextBox"
                               Text="{Binding Path=FirstNameProp,
                                        Mode=TwoWay,
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                               />

   <xctk:WatermarkTextBox Watermark="{Binding SecondNameBtnText}"
                               x:Name="SecondNameTextBox"
                               Text="{Binding Path=LastNameProp,
                                        Mode=TwoWay,
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        <xctk:WatermarkTextBox Watermark="{Binding AdressBtnText}"
                               x:Name="AdressTextBox"
                               Text="{Binding Path=AdressProp,
                                        Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

В code behaind реализован интерфейс  IDataErrorInfo

```
   public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case nameof(FirstNameProp):
                {
                    return UiString.ControlString(FirstNameProp);
                }
                case nameof(LastNameProp):
                {
                    return UiString.ControlString(LastNameProp);
                }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Я не понимаю как правильно выстроить валидацию, чтобы кнопка сохранить изменения была активна только при том условии что все texbox проходят валидацию. Я понимаю что это нужно делать через команду, но вот как связать ошибки всех полей не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, в модель данных добавить свойство `bool AllFieldsIsValid` (ну или что-нибудь в этом роде), и привязать его к свойству `IsEnabled` кнопки "сохранить", при реализации интерфейса `IDataErrorInfo` определить значение для `AllFieldsIsValid`.

PS. костыль конечно, но должно работать)